# How to install netbeans 7.2 on latest ubuntu

Tags: software-installation

I want to install the latest netbeans (i.e. 7.2), But ubuntu software center only gives me 7.0.1.  How to I install netbeans 7.2 on the latest Ubuntu 12.04?  thanks

Comment: [FaqUpgradeInstallation](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqUpgradeInstallation) Here you can find the right answer.

Answer (score 14):

Go to [netbeans download page](http://netbeans.org/downloads/)

Make sure the platform is linux(x86/x64) on the top-right of page
download any version you want from the ones listed below.
you will end up with a netbeans-7.******.sh  file.

for me,

> filename=netbeans-7.2-ml-linux.sh

it will vary depending on the version you choose.

open terminal, go to the directory where its downloaded
eg: I downloaded into my Downloads folder so,I entered the command

```
cd ~/Downloads
```

now execute the .sh file, by entering

```
sudo bash <filename>
```

Comment: Thanks, that works, but this is not part of ubuntu package system and may not benefit from ubuntu upgrade tools.

Comment: Im afraid canonical controls which software goes into the repositories..so the other option is to wait.

Comment: No, Sagar_R, you are completely wrong. Canonical does not control what is in repositories and what is not. Repositories are maintained by Ubuntu community. The fact that the newest NetBeans is not yet in repositories is most likely because the person who maintains this package hadn't yet time to upgrade it, or because nobody has yet picked up this package to push it to repos. Remember that they are all volunteers, and can't donate all their time to Ubuntu.

Comment: Netbeans can auto-update itself, so you do not need ubuntu upgrade tools to be informed of and install latest version of Netbeans.

Comment: @loostro, How to do that? When i click "Help->check for update", it just checking the plug-ins. And then show me this message: `Check your network connection, verify that your proxy settings are configured correctly in the NetBeans IDE, or try again later.`

Comment: I have problem for installing it by this way. Is there any other PPAs for update easily.

Comment: @shgninc it seems you have a problem with a network connection.. it should check for updates and respond with "updates found/ install?" or "no updates found/you are up to date"